# Weird behaviour from using CASE/WHEN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to learn how to use **CASE/WHEN** in **SQL** more specifically, mySQL.

I have two tables: **adhoc_item** and **adhoc_vulnerability**. **ahdoc_item** has one **adhoc_vulnerability** related to it. now **adhoc_vulnerability** *may or may not* have a vulnerability (original_vulnerability_id) attached to it.

In case it doesn't, then I want to return the **name** on itself.

The tables: (or relevant parts thereof)

**ADHOC_ITEM**
[image]

**ADHOC_VULNERABILITY**
[image]
This is my query:

```
SELECT adi.name as item, CASE ahv.original_vulnerability_id
WHEN ISNULL(ahv.original_vulnerability_id) THEN ahv.name
ELSE 'foo'
END NAME
FROM adhoc_item adi
JOIN adhoc_vulnerability ahv ON ahv.id = adi.adhoc_vulnerability_id
```

**and these are the results!**

[image]

Now I know this is a little bit complex but i've been thinking about it for about 2 hours and found no explanation on why that last **item** (which has an **adhoc_vulnerability** with NULL as **original_vulnerability_id**) shows the value that is supposed to appear precisely when that attribute is *not* null!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when `ahv.original_vulnerability_id` is `NULL`, the `ISNULL()` function returns `TRUE` (which is MySQL is the same as `1` but this is irrelevant). So, instead of comparing the column with `NULL`, you are comparing it with `TRUE`.

---

Rewrite the `CASE` expresion as:

```
CASE 
WHEN ISNULL(ahv.original_vulnerability_id) THEN ahv.name
ELSE 'foo'
END NAME
```

or as:

```
CASE 
WHEN ahv.original_vulnerability_id IS NULL THEN ahv.name
ELSE 'foo'
END NAME
```

Comment: Spot on. Was that bad SQL or just how SQL is handled in mySQL?

Comment: No, the conditions `value IS NULL` and `value IS NOT NULL` are standard and valid in all DBMS and can (should) be used for comparing with Null. Not all DBMS have a `ISNULL()` function but if they had (or an equivalent) they would behave as MySQL does in this cae.